# Update pandas column conditionally on contents not working on string column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm using Python 3.6 with all the packages up to date.

I have a df that contains 5 rows that is generated from a SQL statement against an Oracle database. One of the columns is produced by a `listagg()` oracle function which returns a string column.

I need to update another column based on the contents of that listagg column and I'm not able to.

Here is what I've done, but it always set it to 'N'.

`listagg_res['H_FLAG'] = np.where('H' in listagg_res['PGM_LIST'], 'Y', 'N' )`

and

`listagg_res['H_FLAG'] = np.where(np.isin(listagg_res['PGM_LIST'], 'H'), 'Y', 'N' )`

and

`listagg_res['H_FLAG'] = np.where(listagg_res['PGM_LIST'].isin(['H']), 'Y', 'N' )`

Can anyone point out what I'm missing here? Thanks

edit: added the df.isin() attempt. Still doesn't work, sets it all to 'N' regardless.

EDIT: here is an example of my data and the H_FLAG as it should be set

```
+-------------+--------+
|   PGM_ID    | H_FLAG |
+-------------+--------+
| 'H,Z,T,G,H' | Y      |
| 'Z,T,G'     | N      |
| 'Z'         | N      |
| 'H'         | Y      |
+-------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try ?

```
listagg_res['H_FLAG'] = np.where(listagg_res['PGM_LIST'].str.contains('H'), 'Y', 'N' )
```

Comment: No good, at least this one passed. I tried to use the df.isin() method but didn't realize that my "good values" needed to be in a list too. Still, this didn't work.

Comment: @Apc0243 how about post some sample data ?

Comment: Just added, but it's extremely simple. I can't believe this won't work. The column produced by listagg() is an "object" column according to the df.info() method, and when I select individual cells their type is string

Comment: @Apc0243 that is str.contains

Comment: @Apc0243 happy coding :-)